# merge cells with the same value VBA

Tags: excel, vba, merge, cell

I want to merge cells with the same value. I looked at other topics about this but none are the same.

```
WI05000002
WI05000002
WI05000002
WI05000002
WI05000002
WI05000002
WI05000002
WI05000002
WqP01650012
WqP01650012
WqP01650012
WqP01650012
WqP01650012
WqP01650012
WqP01650012
```

Input data:
[image]

Desired result:
[image]

```
Sub scalanie()


Dim P As Range ' deklaracja zmiennej P
  Dim komorka As Range ' deklaracja komórki

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  Set P = Selection.Cells(1, 1)       ' zapamiętaj pierwszą komórkę z zaznaczenia
  For Each komorka In Selection       ' dla każdej komórki w zaznaczeniu
    If komorka = P Then               ' jeśli komórka jest taka sama jak P
      Range(komorka.Offset(0, 0), P).Merge ' scal powyżej komórki do P
                            ' zapamiętaj komórkę
    End If
  Next komorka  ' przejdź do następnej komórki

  Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: What's going wrong? Where is your issue? Did you get any errors? Please give more information and ask a question (see [ask]). Throwing in the code and say *"please fix it for me"* will not work here.

Comment: Why did you change your text data and results into a screenshot?  It is much simpler to copy/paste text data into excel than to have to copy a screenshot manually, in order to help in troubleshooting.

Comment: Also, is there really a need to merge cells. This rarely is a good choice, seeing that  interaction with merged cells is almost always troublesome.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost correct. The issue is that the value of `P` is always set to be equal to the first cell `Set P = Selection.Cells(1, 1)` and it never changes. That is why the second part of your selection (i.e. `WqP01650012`) doesn't merge.

Try using the following code:

```
Sub scalanie()
    Dim P As Range ' deklaracja zmiennej P
    Dim komorka As Range ' deklaracja komórki

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

      For Each komorka In Selection       ' dla kazdej komórki w zaznaczeniu
        On Error Resume Next
        If komorka.Value = komorka.End(xlUp).Value Then
            Range(komorka, komorka.Offset(-1, 0)).Merge
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
      Next komorka  ' przejdz do nastepnej komórki

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Result:

[image]